# Rails routes match starting with a numeric character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a an url like "http://domain.com/1and2" that I wanted to set up in config/routes.rb like this:

match "1and2" => "frontpage#oneandtwo"

(with controllers and views in place).

Running 'rake routes' outputs 'Invalid route name: '1and2''. This error is apparently triggered when you start a match with a numeric character.

Is there a workaround, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What does 'it is not kosher' means? Do you get an error in using it, or do you want to know if it is a good style in using a routes like that?

Comment: yeah sry, that is a bit unclear - I meant to say that 'rake routes' complains and outputs 'Invalid route name: '1and2'' (I'm leaving the original post unedited so your comment still has meaning)

Comment: Update your question, so that others following will get a better start. And just note in your comment, that you have updated your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
match '/:id' => "frontpage#oneandtwo", :constraints => {:id => /1and2/}
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that methods in Ruby cannot start with a number. Since Rails routing will generate an accessor method for each route, you'll get an error.

You can pass by the issue by naming your route differently with the `:as` parameter.

I had an issue where I wanted to redirect from a URI /2012 -- which resulted in an error. I corrected it by adding `:as => current_year` to the routing:

`match "/#{Time.now.year}" => redirect("..."), :as => :current_year`

Further information:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3224